# Properties of $x_0=2003,x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$,$n\geq1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=\arcsin(\sin(x))$ and the sequence $x_0=2003,x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$,$n\geq1$. Which of the following are true: $(x_n)$ is
> A. divergent,
> B. convergent to $0$,
> C. convergent to $l\in(-\frac{\pi}{2},0)$,
> D. unbounded.

Ok, I know that, for $x\in[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$, $\arcsin(\sin(x))=x$ and for $x\in[\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}]$, $\arcsin(\sin(x))=\pi-x$. I took in consideration the fact that this funcion is periodic with a period of $2\pi$ and that $2003\in[\frac{\pi}{2}+637\pi,\frac{3\pi}{2}+639\pi]$, therefore, as $639$ is odd, $\arcsin(\sin(2003))=2003$, and the sequence is constant. Then A is false, B is true, C is false, D is false.

I have a feeling that this ended too fast and I did a mistake. Any help, please?

Comment: It's not true that $arcsin(2003) = 2003$, because $arcsin(x) \in [ -\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \dfrac{\pi}{2}]$

Comment: @NeoFanatic, the function is extended such that we have all the reals.

Comment: @AnatolDenicula The sequence converges. In fact, it stops at $x_1 = f(x_0)$  (this means $x_1 =x_2 =x_3=...$) because $x_1 \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$ then $x_{n+1} = x_n$ for all $n \ge 1$

Comment: Why does $x_1$ belong to that interval?

Comment: @AnatolDenicula Because $arcsin(z) \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$. Your conclusion is nearly ok (the sequence is constant) because it stops at $x_1$ (and not at $x_0 = 2003$). I think you should choose the anwser C.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. Thank you!